# Dynamic form with Ajax in Wicket

Tags: ajax, forms, dynamic, drop-down-menu, wicket

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

For example: I select something from the dropdown (Sender). Then below the Dropdown-Field a new Label and uneditable TextField should be displayed, which takes the input from other components. (see screenshot).

An example or tutorial-links would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at wicket-examples. Your case seems to me like a combination of OnChangeAjaxBehaviorPage and ChoicePage.